# String split by commas but skip one comma

Tags: java

i have this string:

```
"O2TV, SportTV", Netflix /603605506, 2016-01-02 15:15:01
```

I need split it into array[3] by commas, but skip comma in quotation marks. Is there any simple way, like one split command? Thanks!

Comment: I strongly suspect you actually want a proper CSV handling library that handles quoted strings correctly, such as [Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) (which I haven't used, but Apache projects tend to be of at least reasonable quality).

Comment: You can use String.split() with a regex: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/string/java-string-split-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to skip all occurrences of comma in double quotes then you can refer below solution,

```
public class Sample {

    private static final String REGEX = ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString = "\"O2TV, SportTV\", Netflix /603605506, 2016-01-02 15:15:01";
        String[] tokens = inputString.split(REGEX, -1);

        for (String token : tokens) {
            System.out.println(token);
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on exactly what you want.

If you want to always skip the first comma you can do something like

```java
String firstSection = csvString.substring(0, csvString.indexOf(","));
String[] remainingParts = csvString.substring(csvString.indexOf(",", csvString.indexOf(","))).split(",");
```

On the other had, if you want to skip any commas inside quotes, then you need a full on CSV parser.